# Graceful exit on WebView1 / Legacy Edge not working

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I submitted my add-in for publishing but Microsoft found a compatibility issue with WebView1 / Legacy edge not exiting gracefully. Currently testing on a version of Outlook that uses this the add-in won't open at all and is stuck with an "Add-in is loading" message.

The add-in uses a dialog box. On startup I read the userAgent to check for the browser

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident") === -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge/") === -1) {
    openDialog(e, `${getUrl()}?mode=attach`, "attach");
} else {
    openDialog(e, `${getUrl()}?mode=unsupported`, "unsupported");
}
```

I think the issue is something to do with my requirement set (and the DialogApi) not being supported in these older versions of Outlook

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets>
        <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.9" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

My confusion here is how do I provide a graceful exit on versions of Outlook where my add-in cannot even start due to the incompatibility? I believe my browser detection code does work just it is never reached due to the above incompatibility.

Is there a way to determine this beforehand? And then use a taskpane (Is this compatible with older versions?) to show the graceful exit message?

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated! If you need any more info from me I am happy to edit this with more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the supported versions of host applications. See [Dialog API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/dialog-api-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview) for more information. Also you may find the [Outlook JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=excel-js-preview&tabs=xmlmanifest) helpful.

Requirement set support varies by Office application, the version of the Office application, and the platform on which it is running. For example, `DialogApi 1.2` is not supported on one-time purchase versions of Office before Office 2021, but `DialogApi 1.1` is supported on all one-time purchase versions back to Office 2013. You want your add-in to be installable on every combination of platform and Office version that supports the APIs that it uses, so you should always specify in the manifest the minimum version of each requirement set that your add-in requires.

You can test at runtime to discover whether the user's Office supports a requirement set with the `isSetSupported` method. Pass the requirement set's name and the minimum version as parameters. If the requirement set is supported, `isSetSupported` returns `true`. The following code shows an example.

```
if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('DialogApi', '1.2'))
{
   // Code that uses API members from the DialogApi 1.2 requirement set.
} else {
   // Provide diminished experience here. E.g., run alternate code when the user's host application is one-time purchase (which does not support DialogApi 1.2).
}
```

See [Specify Office applications and API requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements) for more information.

Comment: I have added MailBox 1.9 as the minimum version. From everything I have read the add-in shouldn't even be available on earlier versions of Outlook. Microsoft tested it on ```16.0.11629``` and according to that Dialog API requirement set it shouldn't be available on that version. But as it is required to pass certification I'm not sure how to provide the graceful exit. Ideally the add-in wouldn't be available at all on versions that do not support DialogApi but I don't think that is an option for passing certification.

Comment: If I add ```<Set Name="DialogApi" MinVersion="1.1" />``` then I am unable to install even on my latest version of Outlook as it is "unsupported" (But the dialog box still works if I exclude this from the requirement set)

Comment: I've updated the post to include some bits about requirements sets.